# datagridview sorted by id descending order c# in winform application

Tags: c#, winforms, sorting, visual-studio-2012, datagridview

I'm working in VS2012 on a C# WinForms app. By default when clicking on a column header in a DataGridView it not sorts that column Ascending, you can then click on the column header again to sort it Descending.

so the initial click sorts Descending then the second click sorts Ascending and I haven't been able to figure out how to do this. Does anyone know?

Comment: You want to sort it descending first before ascending when you first click the column header? Is that what you are saying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sort it always in `Descending` order, try this code:

```
void dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{      
  dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns[dataGridView1.SortedColumn.Name],ListSortDirection.Descending);
}
```

If you want to alternate and start with Descending first and then ascending on the 2nd one. You could declare a global variable (at least in your Form), like:

```
Boolean lastSortedAscending = false;
```

Then your `ColumnHeaderMouseClick` event would probably look like this:

```
void dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{      
   lastSortedAscending = !lastSortedAscending;
   if ( lastSortedAscending) 
      { 
       dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns[dataGridView1.SortedColumn.Name],ListSortDirection.Descending); 
      }
   else
     {
       dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns[dataGridView1.SortedColumn.Name],ListSortDirection.Ascending); 
     }
}
```

Or without declaring a global variable - you could also do this, like:

```
void dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{      

if (dataGridView1.SortOrder.ToString() == "Ascending") // Check if sorting is Ascending
    { 
       dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns[dataGridView1.SortedColumn.Name],ListSortDirection.Descending); 
      }
   else
     {
       dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns[dataGridView1.SortedColumn.Name],ListSortDirection.Ascending); 
     }
}
```